# How to connect a thermal printer to an ESP32?

Tags: printing, connection, esp32

I want to attach my GOOJPRT Thermal Printer (I believe model QR701, communication RS232) to my ESP32 but I cannot seem to get them working.

I tried all the Adafruit Thermal Printer library examples but get the same error each and every time:

```
"Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module."
```

I guess the libraries are not meant for the ESP32.
I also tried the ["Thermal Printer Library" by Larry Bank](https://github.com/bitbank2/Thermal_Printer) (which should be compatible with the ESP32 according to its github docs) but there I cannot figure out how to connect the wires of thermal printer to the ESP32 correctly.

Of course, I do not ask for a specific solution, I am just looking for someone to point me in the right direction!

[image]

[This is an image of the exact thermal printer I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBHeI.jpg)

*Full error message from Adafruit Thermal Printer examples:*

```
C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial-master\SoftwareSerial.cpp:41:27: fatal error: avr/interrupt.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Multiple libraries were found for "Adafruit_Thermal.h"
 Used: C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_Thermal_Printer_Library
 Not used: C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit-Thermal-Printer-Library-master
Multiple libraries were found for "SoftwareSerial.h"
 Used: C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Arduino\libraries\SoftwareSerial-master
 Not used: C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\Arduino\libraries\EspSoftwareSerial
exit status 1
Error compiling for board ESP32 Dev Module
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add some details to your attempts at compiling the Adafruit Thermal Printer library - what did you do, where did it fail and how. The high-level error message you've quoted is useless. The second library pointed by you is using Bluetooth Low Energy to talk to the printer; and the printer model is different from yours (same manufacturer, though) so it might not be compatible. Finally, you really need to find some technical documentation on your printer - detailing the connections, protocol etc.

Comment: @Tarmo I added the full error message on the bottom of my post. My attempts of compiling for the ESP32 and the thermal printer were merely opening the sketch and hooking up all the necessary wires. I understand from what you're saying that the library by Larry Bank is useless, good to know! Good tip to also look into documentation, I have tried that too but with no avail so far, I will continue my search a bit more

Comment: Well, Larry Bank's library is not useless if you want to use BLE and the two different devices respond to the same printer protocol. In the mean time - your Adafruit sketch goes straight to compiling the AVR variant of some SoftwareSerial library (instead of picking the ESP32 variant like it should). I've no experience with Arduino, so can't help there. But perhaps creating a new, specific question with relevant arduino tags added would help.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to use the <HardwareSerial.h> library. SoftwareSerial is for Arduino boards.
2. "Thermal Printer Library" by Larry Bank is for GOOJPRT PT-210 and use Bluetooth. Won't work for qr-701.
3. Instead of using Adafruit Library, you can try with this:
   [ThermalPrinter](https://github.com/BinaryWorlds/ThermalPrinter)

Quick start:

1. Import libraries:

```
#include "TPrinter.h"
#include <HardwareSerial.h>
```

2. Set baudrate and pins.

```
const int printerBaudrate = 9600;  // or 19200 usually
const byte rxPin = 16;   // check datasheet of your board
const byte txPin = 17;   // check datasheet of your board
const byte dtrPin = 27;  // optional
const byte rsePin = 4;   // direction of transmission, max3485
```

You need to use boad with max3485(for 3V3 logic lvl) or similar, if you have printer with rs232.
Necessary in my case. I use board UART - RS485 3,3V - ARK/RJ11 - Waveshare 4777

3. Init

```
HardwareSerial mySerial(1);
Tprinter myPrinter(&mySerial, printerBaudrate);

void setup() {
  micros();
  mySerial.begin(printerBaudrate, SERIAL_8N1, rxPin, txPin);  // must be 8N1 mode
  pinMode(rsePin, OUTPUT);     // optional
  digitalWrite(rsePin, HIGH);  // optional

  // myPrinter.enableDtr(dtrPin, LOW); // optional
  myPrinter.begin();
}
```